# How to Switch the branch an commit with Tortoise Hg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have two branches named X and Y. X is previously created and y is the latest one. Now I am at branch 'Y' and I have modified some files. I need to commit the files which I have modified and I need to commit the changes to 'X' branch instead of 'Y' branch. How can I do this with Mercury Hg or Tortoise Hg? (How to Switch to 'x' branch and commit the changes?)

Comment: Do you mean "branch" in the topological sense (a parallel development flow) or in the coloring sense of Mercurial's named-branches?

Answer (score 0):

I use Shelving for such operation: https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/shelve.html

While you're on 'Y' branch, put all your changes to shelf. Then switch to 'X' branch and restore changes from your shelf.

Answer (score 0):

You could

- Commit it to Y branch
- Then transplant/grave it to X branch
- Then strip changeset from Y branch

As result it's look like you commited it to X instead of Y

Answer (score 0):

If you have not committed the changes then you should be able to do the following:

```
hg update X
hg commit
```

Unless you've changed some of the same files in the same places within the file, this should be sufficient. If you have, then your `hg update X` command should fail. You have a few options at this point.

You can use Mercurial Queues (mq).

You can put your current changes into a patch queue:

```
hg qnew stufftomove -e
```

You'll be presented with whatever editor you use to create a commit message. Go ahead and fill in your commit message with whatever you want it to be when it is ultimately committed. If you don't use -e, it will just create the patch queue with no commit message. Later you can make a commit message with `hg qrefresh -e` if you want.

After the patch queue is created, pop it off with:

```
hg qpop
```

Now move to the X branch:

```
hg update X
```

Now push the patch queue on. This will apply the patch file:

```
hg qpush
```

This can either go on cleanly, or if you did have merge conflicts, you'll get a message that .rej files have been created. Those show you the parts of the changes that could not be applied automatically.

If you have .rej files, manually apply the pieces that didn't work and then run 
    hg qrefresh

This will update the patch file with the new changes.

When everything looks like what you want it to, you can convert the patch queue to a real commit with

```
hg qfinish stufftomove
```

Your file changes should now be committed on the branch you want them to be on.

Alternatively, if you already committed the changes on the wrong branch, and have not pushed your changes (or had them pulled) to a remote repository, you can do this:

```
hg qimport -r <revision to import>
```

At this point, continue the above instructions starting with `hg qpop`.

If you can be more specific about the state of the files and branches, I can help more specifically. In any case, I hope this helps.

*Side note*: If you've got merge conflicts in the steps above and don't like dealing with .rej files, you can use `hg rebase` which will allow you to resolve the conflicts in your favorite merge tool (or whatever tool you've got configured). Hope this helps.